# Plaid Sandbox Android APP Program Keeps Refreshing

Tags: android, android-studio, plaid

The code that I'm using was imported directly from this example code:
https://github.com/plaid/link/tree/master/webviews/examples/android

When I run the app in Android Studio on a Nexus 5X emulator I see this:

[Empty Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djmst.png)

It then goes to the loading screen:

[Loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZIar.png)

The app then switches between the two as if it were constantly refreshing. I see the empty menu then the loading screen pops up, then back to the empty menu then loading screen again.

I'm very new to Plaid so there might be something very simple that I'm missing but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In the initialize link step, replace `[PLAID_PUBLIC_KEY]` with the public key provided to you. If you haven't registered for an account with Plaid, you have to do that first.

```
linkInitializeOptions.put("key", "[PLAID_PUBLIC_KEY]");
```

An HTTP request is sent with the public key, and the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` function will keep getting called upon response without a valid public key, perpetuating the refresh cycle that you see.